# How To use different segues for different UTableView Sections and pass data

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am using a `UITableView` with two sections, I use an array called `sections` for the section header titles, and an array called `sectionItems` which holds two arrays of string value to populate the sections.

```
let sections = ["Section 1", "Section 2"]

var sectionItems = [ ["One","Two", "Three", "Four"], ["Another One"] ]
```

The UITableView displays the data fine, however I am trying to segue when the user selects a table view cell. The problem is I have two different segues for the two different sections.

How can I use each segue for the appropriate section ?

This is what I was trying,

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)


    //Optional error occurs here for section property 
    let section = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.section

    if section == 0 {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("sectionOneSegue", sender: cell)
    } else if section == 1 {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("sectionTwoSegue", sender: cell)
    }

}
```

However this give me an optional error when declaring the property section.

Also when the segue is initiated I am trying to pass the relevant data to the detail controller.

Here I am trying to make sure in the sectionItems array I use the first array within the array by using the section number, then the exact string value for the selected cell row.

```
    if segue.identifier == "sectionOneSegu" {

        let navController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let detailController = navController.topViewController as! DetailViewController
        var row = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row


        detailController.upcomingType = sectionItems[1][row]            
        detailController.mode = 1

    }
```

I am unsure if this is correct. Can someone help me out on why the error is occurring when selecting the cell row and how to fix it to use the correct segue ? And how can I pass the relevant data ?

Comment: For getting the section number, you can just use: `indexPath.section`.

Comment: you can link segues up to prototype cells, then when you touch a cell it will call your prepareForSegue method where you can check the segue.identifier property. From there you would extract the selected row as you do now and get the data from your table data. What it seems like is that the index path for the selected row is nil which is why you are unable to extract the section value. In your current example that is irrelevent because you have the indexPath as an argument. I don't know when apple updates the state of the cells to be selected, but it's possible its not until after didSelectRow

Comment: FYI, you should never call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier from outside cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you don't need to get the cell in your 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' method, so the first line where you create a reference to the cell is unnecessary.

You have an index path that has a row and section index within it, use that to obtain the data out of your sectionItems array e.g

```
let data = sectionItems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

switch indexPath.section {
case 0:
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("sectionOneSegue", sender: data)
case 1:
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("sectionTwoSegue", sender: data)
default:
    break
}
```

That should be all you need within that method.

You can then override the prepareForSegue method and check the segue.identifier property to see which segue has been performed and extract the destinationViewController from there. Once you have the view controller you can pass your data to it through a property on the view controller.

```
if segue.identifier == "sectionOneSegue" {

    guard let data = sender as? String,
    newViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? NewViewController else {
        return
    }

    newViewController.data = data
}
```

In the above code I'm making sure that the sender is the expected data type (the one sent from the above performSegueWithIdentifier method) and that the destination controller is the one that I want, then as soon as I know everything is correct I'm setting the property on the destination controller with the data that I want to send to it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I should also add that you should probably move the identifier to a constant somewhere so you don't get any unexpected errors caused by spelling mistakes etc.

Comment: Also remember that I've written 'NewViewController' simply to demonstrate an implementation, you should replace that with the name of the actual view controller class that you are using ;)

Comment: BTW I still have an issue with getting the row value, I get an optional error for the following  `let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let selectedObject = Objects[indexPath!.row]`

Comment: I am trying to pass a NSManagedObject to the destination view controller from an array using the row value from the section

Comment: Where are you putting the `let indexPath = ...`? The index path is given to you in the method arguments in 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath'.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are inside `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, you do not need to look for index path of the selection like this:

```
let section = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.section
```

The desired `indexPath` is given to you in a variable, so all you need to do is

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("sectionOneSegue", sender: cell)
} else if indexPath.section == 1 {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("sectionTwoSegue", sender: cell)
}
```

or use an array that gives you segue name for section index, like this:

```
private static let segueForIndex = ["sectionOneSegue", "sectionTwoSegue"]
...
self.performSegueWithIdentifier(MyClass.segueForIndex[indexPath.section], sender: cell)
```